# Are WebForm Aspx pages out of support?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webpages

According to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/aspnet

- ASP.NET Web API
- ASP.NET Web Pages 2

  Support ended July 1st, 2019

Running as a Web Site (instead of a web application), makes things fuzzy. Yes, this is legacy code...

My impression is that WebForm is out of support.

It seems to be classed as a "Tools"
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2902020/support-lifecycle-for-asp-net-web-stack

Also:
Microsoft “What is Web Forms” has not been updated for almost 6 years… https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/what-is-web-forms

But I cannot find any clear statement... What is there can be interpreted different ways.

Comment: That document lists specific versions that are EOL'd. I'm not sure why anyone would be working with a "web site" vs a "web project" in this day and age unless you're just supporting legacy code.

Comment: ASP.NET Web Pages 3 is listed in the "Supported Versions" table. Additionally, ASP.NET Web API 2 is also listed there.

Comment: When you ask about ASPX, are you talking about Web Forms? Because that's part of .NET Framework, so its support policy is tied to that.